# SQL запрос в C# возвращает список одних и тех же данных

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, linq, ssms

Таблица Comments связана внешними ключами с Videos и Users и имеет свой Id, таким образом пользователь может оставлять несколько комментариев под видео. Но при получении данных в C# возвращается список из одинаковых значений там, где совпадают внешние ключи. По всей видимости результаты сравниваются по внешним связям, а не по первичному ключу, при том, что в MS SQL тот же запрос работает как и должен. В чём проблема, как это фиксить?

Код класса Comment :

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public Video Video { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Связь в DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasKey(v => new { v.UserId, v.VideoUrl });
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasOne(v => v.User).WithMany(u => u.Comments).HasForeignKey(v => v.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasOne(v => v.Video).WithMany(v => v.Comments).HasForeignKey(v => v.VideoUrl);
```

Схема в MS SQL

[image: Схема]

Результат выполнения запроса

[image: Результаты]

Comment: `video.Comments` - не важно, я просто показываю, что в `var comments` (куда я пытаюсь записать список из комментариев) записываются три одинаковых значения с заголовком от первого найденного элемента (остальные параметры там тоже идентичные - копипаста первого найденного элемента).

Comment: Зачем Вы добавляете комментарий, а не редактируете сам вопрос? И странно у Вас выглядит таблица Videos... Почему в качестве ключа не используете Id, а Url? Если Url должен быть уникальным, то можно добавить индекс, а так при смене Url у вас потеряются связи...

Comment: Я комментарий оставил как ответ на вопрос человека в форума, но он удалил свои комментарии. Url потому и использую, потому что у видео не меняется Url, поэтому смысла нет использовать два статичных параметра. У пользователя, к примеру, я использую и Id, и Url, потому что у него я сделал изменение ссылки на канал.

Comment: В MS SQL Management Studio включите профайлинг (Tools -> SQL Server Profiler) и посмотрите какие запросы приходят. Помимо этого Вы не привели код каким Вы выбираете записи. Также не помешал бы код классов и конфигурации DbContext для Video и User.

Comment: Так я же привёл код в `FromSqlRaw`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением `AsNoTracking()`. По всей видимости Entity Framework каким-то образом индексирует данные по внешним ключам, игнорируя первичный. Отключая отслеживание индексации нет.
Также для изменения данных нужно отправлять SQL запросы напрямую через `ExecuteSqlAsync()`

Comment: Добавьте столбец id в таблицу Videos и посмотрите будет ли это будет работать, а так Вы лишаетесь многих преимуществ ORM, т.к. явно прописываете SQL запросы, которые могут отличаться от БД к БД. Ничего страшного нет в том, что у Вас в таблице будет находится столбец со "статическим" значением.